# NULL values after merging layers with ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, null

in ArcGIS Pro I have two point layers, "Output" and "Output_2". Using the "Near" tool, I examine which points are close to each other, select some from "Output" with "Select by Attributes" and then add them to "Output_2" with "Merge". When I do this manually, everything works fine. The selection is added to the layer.

[image: Attribute table]

If I follow the exact same steps in ModelBuilder, the points of the selection are transferred correctly. However, the values of the "Output_2" have only NULL values except for the "ID" and "Shape".

What can be the reason for this?

[image: ModelBuilder]

Comment: According to [Merge (Data Management) - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/merge.htm):  "To manage the fields in the output dataset and the contents of those fields, use the [Field Map](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/field-map.htm) parameter."  Did you set up an attribute field mapping?

Comment: I think, your're right. I tried some things in this section and I am not sure, where I was wrong, but now it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @bixb0012 and DMK,  I believe this is a bug in ArcPro 3. I had reported this a few months ago to ESRI, it seems that the field mapping is broken, they will inevitably claim "its by design" but it breaks all sorts of model logic. I discovered the problem when collecting datasets in a sub-model to feed into a merge tool in a master model. One has to manually click on the reset fields mapping button for it all to work, so making model tools impossible to run.  Right now Merge in ArcPro modelbuilder is unusable, works fine in ArcMap...